# session in codeigniter Undefined property: CI::$session

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm having trouble loading my view on my login page . Having problems with the session here . I have a helper class that $ key security is part of it . But I think it is to do a session as an error saying .

I thought I had prepared a num lines was not sure whether also that it may cause.

```html
<?php $this->load->library('session');
      if(!$this->session->user_email)
      { ?>
            <li <?php echo ($controller=="login" )? "class='active'": ""?>>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('login') ?>">
             Login
            </a>
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('login/logout') ?>">
                    Logout
                </a>
            </li>
<?php } ?>
```

this problem

```html
Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$session

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 145

Backtrace:
```

Comment: can you providing more code which can be easy to solve.

Comment: You load the session library on controller or autoload.php not on view.

Comment: how to load the session on view ?

Comment: Have you read through here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Usually this is the right way to load the session since most of the times it will be accessed through out the application, 
under "config/config.php"
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'upload', 'cart');
Let me know whats the reason you are trying to load it in your View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing you code, you should not do it in helper. You should do it in your View.php. In your View.php, should use `$CI = & get_instance();`.

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');  //change from $this->load->library('session');
$CI->session->user_data('user_email');  // change from $this->session->user_email
```

Get the html code from view as a variable:

```
$html_code = $this->load->view('folder/view_name',$data,true);
```

Comment: view empty if the code you, problem null but view null

Comment: whats is problem null?

Comment: your helper.php should not include the html code. You should do in view better than do it in helper.php

Comment: @YuliIswadi if resolved by this answer, please give a tick for others to get answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

go to autoload.php in config folder and 
replage this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```